# Xlwings takes a lot of time to write large datasets in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have a pandas data frame that has **517 rows** and **13 columns**. I am trying to write the data from python to an Excel Sheet using xlwings. **My issue is that it takes more than 35 mins for xlwings to write the data in the excel spreadsheet**.

```
ws.range("A2").options(header=False, index=False, chunksize=10000).value =qryPCPMonthlyDomainSpend
```

I also tried to write the data in batches of 200 rows and what I found was that it writes the data pretty quick for the first 400 rows after that it takes forever to write the remaining data. How can I speed up this process?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: This data is being imported to an excel sheet that contains macros. After the import is done, a pivot table is created by the macros. Therefore, using the traditional method to write the data in an excel sheet will not work in this case.

Comment: That’s not a huge amount of data, so should not take that long at all. I’m not too familiar with xlwings: could the sheet be trying to auto-calculate at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested writing a DataFrame (517 x 13) into Excel with `pandas=1.3.5` and `xlwings=0.25.3`. It takes about 1 second.

```py
# project.py
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def insert_test_df(sheet, rows, columns):
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    # Private pandas utility functions for testing
    pd._testing._N = rows
    pd._testing._K = columns
    df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
    wb.sheets[sheet].range("A1").value = df
    return df
```

Above is code on Python side and below is VBA code in Excel side (project.xlsm).

```vb
Sub InsertLargeDataFrame()
    mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
    RunPython "import " & mymodule & ";" & mymodule & ".insert_test_df('Sheet2', 517, 13)"
End Sub
```

I suggest that you write "raw" data one one Excel sheet and then do other transformations on other sheet.
This should avoid any interference by Excel auto-calculation functionality, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet so I will have to use the answer area, but I use xlwings daily for my finance model and I can paste 5000 x 20 in fractions of a second. Are you sure the pasting is what is causing problems? I would test pasting the data into a blank workbook so you eliminate any weird macros running, or calculating of data while it is pasting. 35 minutes leads me to believe that something is calculating the data when it is pasted and is hanging the process. You also say it writes the first 400 relatively quickly. Maybe there is something in the last data? You could inspect the dataframe and see what the size is, df.info(). Maybe it is huge and you don't realize it?

All I use to paste my df's is what you are doing, df.value = rng.